# Cross species effects of Apis mellifera queen pheromones

Tags: species

I am looking for studies that show effects of *Apis mellifera* queen pheromones on other species. An example of [one such study](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep36041) is where *A. mellifera* queen pheromones deactivated the ovaries of *Drosophila melanogaster* females. Similarly queen pheromone from *Apis mellifera scutellate* [can deactivate worker ovaries](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-26060-w) in a different sub- species, *Apis mellifera capensis* (however, this is a sub species effect and not cross species). If anyone else knows any other studies of cross species effects, it would be highly appreciated if it could be pointed out.